# Как мне прокидывать пропсы по условию

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Мне надо, чтобы какой-то элемент отображался по условию.

`style: boolean;` 
  `visible:string;`

`<Line className="line" style={{ display: props.visible}}></Line>`

Если visible === true, то style === block
или visible === false, то style === none

Comment: Вы описываете переменные `style: boolean; visible:string;` однако в условиях у вас `visible: boolean`, а `style: string`... Так какие именно у вас типы данных и условия рендера компонента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, что ваши переменные это `props` и тип данных мы берем из условия, а не из описания.

Условный рендер можно сделать так:

```
return (
   <>
   {props.visible && <Line className="line" style={{ display: props.style}}></Line>}
   </>
)
```

Если `props.visible` будет true, тогда будет отрендерен компонент `Line` и в стиль `display` будет подставлено значение переменной `props.style`

Comment: Благодарю! Сработало

Answer (score 0):

```js
const visible = document.getElementById("myElement").style.visible; // ищем необходимый элемент
const style = visible ? "block" : "none";
//условие - если visible = true, тогда style = block, иначе - none
```

```html
<Line className="line" style={style}></Line>
```

Comment: document.getElementById в reactjs это очень плохая практика

Comment: Не спорю, что поиск элемента таким образом может выдать кучу багов,  в данный момент времени, использовал её для наглядности

Comment: Нет, это в целом не подход к разработке в reactjs. Вы ищите непонятный элемент в DOM дереве непонятно зачем, хотя вопрос про передачу props значений и их обработку в компонент reactJS.

Comment: Согласен, не очень хороший подход