# UseState который содержит массив с объектами, не рендериться на страницу

Tags: reactjs

Есть массив с объектами в useState "selected", я перебираю нужный массив в зависимости от id в useParams. И при вписании нужных данных внутрь HTML страница не отображается вовсе, изчезают все элементы DOM.

Функционал: Суть состоит в том, что при клике на новость, открывается страница с той новостью, расширенная (думаю вы поняли). И при клике распознается ID и PATH с помощью useParams.

*как выглядит массив selected:

```
selected[{id:1, date:..., title: Заголовок,...}, {...}].
```

Значение `useParams` будет равна 1, а значит будет выбран объект с id = 1.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './ExtendedNews.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ExtendedNews = () => {
    const {id} = useParams();
    const[selected, setSelected] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/myNews')
        .then(response => {
            setSelected(response.data.find((obj) => {
                return obj.id === +id;
            }));
            console.log(selected)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }, [selected, id]);

    return (
        <div className='extendedNews'>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="postWrap">
                    <h1 className="pageName">{**selected.title**}</h1>
                    <span className="date">{**selected.date**}</span>
                    <div className='textWrap'>{**selected.content**}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ExtendedNews;
```

[image: Ошибки в консоле]

Comment: Когда компонент рендерится первый раз, ваш selected === undefined. Задайне начальное состояние или добавьте проверку в рендер, что selected чем то заполнен. Вот пример [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460236/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460236/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8e/1460244#1460244)

Comment: Что означает вот это `{**selected.title**}` ? Я про две звездочки