# Пытаюсь вызвать ошибку через нажатие по кнопке, ничего не работает, что делать?

Tags: reactjs, vk-mini-apps

Импортируемые зависимости:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { Panel, PanelHeader, Header, Group, CellButton, Snackbar } from '@vkontakte/vkui';
import { Icon28ErrorCircleOutline, Icon24LogoVk } from '@vkontakte/icons';
```

Функция вызова ошибки:

```
const openError = () => {
    <Snackbar before={<Icon28ErrorCircleOutline fill="var(--vkui--color_icon_negative)" />}>Не удалось получить токен, попробуйте заного!</Snackbar>
}
```

Кнопка отвечающая за это + код всего модуля Home:

```
const Home = ({ id, go, fetchedToken, catchError }) => (
    <Panel id={id}>
        <PanelHeader>Example</PanelHeader>
        {fetchedToken &&
        <Group header={<Header mode="secondary">Кнопочкииии</Header>}>
            <CellButton before={<Icon24LogoVk width={25} height={25} />} centered='true' mode='danger' onClick={openError}>Give me a error</CellButton>
        </Group>}
    </Panel>
);
```

При нажатии кнопки происходит НИЧЕГО!

Comment: Почему? При нажатии функция отрабатывает, только ничего не возвращает. А если и вернет, то ее результат никак не обрабатывается

Comment: [Вот тут посмотрите пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460236/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8e/1460244#1460244) только вместо пропсов задайте себе переменную-флаг. По умолчанию false, a в функции пусть меняется значение на true