# Содержимое динамической шапки

Tags: веб-программирование, nextjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу написать компонент header, но суть его такая, что он везде разный. Я не имею понятие как это лучше сделать. На скриншоте можно увидеть, что в каждом разделе у нас header отличается. Как реализовать такой компонент? Если вам не трудно, можете пожалуйста показать небольшим примером)))

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Лучше сделать 3 компонента и отображать их по условию в компоненте хедер. В сам хэдер передавать пропсы с текущей страницей(допустил). Или можно использовать useLocation для определения текущей страницы

Comment: Не, не создавать 3 компонента шапки - бред же :) Хочу одним компонентом обойтись как-то :)

Comment: Не бред. У вас 3 шапки разные. Потом функционал будет разный появляться. Можете конечно все в один запихнуть, однако это не реакт-подход. В компонент передавайте значение, а в рендере проверяйте его и отображайте. [пример условного рендеринга](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460236/1460244#1460244). [Пример декомпозиции компонента с условным рендером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463823)

Comment: Второй вариант хороший. Буду пробовать)

Comment: А вот еще вопрос, получается мне нужно создать два компонента? Ну, первый у нас будет компонент там где аватарка, но вместо аватарки там может быть фильтр, поэтому вместо этого нужно просто children передать? А для аватарки и фильтра создать компоненты отдельно и потом просто передавать в children